# run existing java program with cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I have a running java program which converts a json file into another file format. Everything works great.
For the implementation I decided to use the MVC pattern.

Now I want to implement the whole conversion routine so that I can use a command prompt but I never worked with that and don't know how to achieve this at all.

My thoughts were:

1. Open `cmd` and navigate to the main.java-file.
2. Print out the whole possibilities (the user should be able to enter the dir of the source file and the target dir, the user should be able to choose the target format).
3. If everything has been entered by the user, the conversion routine should be started by pushing ENTER.

Help would be really nice. For the moment I just know how to compile (`javac helloWorld.java`) and print "Hello World!" by exeuting a program with `java helloWorld`...

Comment: Uhm, you'd better learn to program in Java first.

Comment: Great advice, thank you... but if you have read my question I wrote a whole converter in java...

Comment: Well, you said you only knew how to compile and print "Hello World"

Comment: Yeah that is indeed the case but this is just limited to the use of cmd in combination with java.

Comment: Do you want to make the program interactive as in printing a text menu and asking for answers? (In that case `Scanner(System.in)` you will find on each homework question on SO. IF you only want to pass a parameter from cmd to java, then it is all there in arg[0]..[arg.length]. On cmd you need to call `java -cp . package.Main arg1 arg2` when you are in the parent of the folder "package" or you better generate a JAR and start it with `java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2`

Comment: @eckes: If I understood you right, you can just pass real parameters instead of "arg1" and "arg2"?

Comment: @X-fate yes, that is the idea behind `main(String[] arg)`. You can also use -D (before the class-name or -jar argument) to specify system properties, which you then can get. This makes it easy without any CLI parser library to support optional flags like `java -Dverbose=true -jar bla.jar arg1 arg2`.

Comment: @eckes: Would you mind to post this as a "real" answer, so I can accept it?:)

Comment: @X-Fate sure, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction between a shell/command prompt and the started Java program is very similar to the way it works in C programs*. The `main()` method receives arguments as strings from the command line (or from any other parent process which executes the java runtime).

In Java you get an array of strings. You need to decide yourself which string has what meaning.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {     // traditional or String ... args
  System.out.println("You have " + arg.length + " arguments);
  if (arg.length >= 1) System.out.println("First: " + arg[0]);
}
```

When starting a Java runtime with arguments, it is important to note, that arguments start after the class name (or the JAR name):

```
java -cp . package.Main arg0 arg1 ...
java -jar package.jar arg0 arg1 ...
```

The Java runtime also has an mechanism to specify system properties on the command line. This is done with the `-D` option.

```
java -Dverbose=yes -jar package.jar arg0 arg1 ...
java -jar package.jar -Dverbose=yes arg1 ... //not a system property but arg[0]
```

It is important, that this option is specified before the class/jar-name, otherwise it will not be processed by the runtime, but you will see another argument.

```
String verbose = System.getProperty("verbose", "false");
```

The reason why system properties are useful: you can use them for optional control, so you do not have to worry about recognizing arguments (there are a number of libraries out there which can do that but for small tools I think it is overkill).

BTW: there are some interactions between shells/prompts and started programs when using wildcards (`*` and `?`) and whitespace/quoting - those are OS specific.

<sub>* in C the first argument `args[0]` is the program name, in java `arg[0]` is the first argument after the class name.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The [apache commons cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) project provides utilities for parsing command line arguments and providing help menu. This makes it pretty simple to handle the args provided to your main method.

You will also need to provide scripts to assemble your class path. You can look at the [maven app assembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) for ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.